# Does anyone know why I getting this eslint error message when installing airbnb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint

I'm been trying to get airbnb installed in my eslint config for the last day or so.
Currently, I'm using vscode with the eslint plugin installed, also I have eslint install locally on my machine using npm.  I previous had it installed globally and still had the same result.  I can't find much about this error thats why I'm posting here to see if someone else has figure out why this error is happening

I keep getting this error message:

```
/Users/shaunearley/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb/rules/react.js:
Configuration for rule "react/jsx-wrap-multilines" is invalid:  Value " [object Object]" should NOT have additional properties.  
Referenced from: /Users/shaunearley/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb/index.js Referenced from: /Users/shaunearley/.eslintrc
```

Below is my eslintrc file.  I also have prettier installed however I don't think that's causing the error because I've commented out airbnb in my eslintrc file and everything seems to work.

```
$ {
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/react"
  ],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 8,
     "ecmaFeatures": {
     "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
     "impliedStrict": true,
     "classes": true
  }
},
   "env": {
   "browser": true,
   "node": true,
   "jquery": true,
   "jest": true
},
"rules": {
"no-debugger": 0,
"no-alert": 0,
"no-unused-vars": [
  1,
  {
    "argsIgnorePattern": "res|next|^err"
  }
],
"prefer-const": [
  "error",
  {
    "destructuring": "all",
  }
],
"arrow-body-style": [
  2,
  "as-needed"
],
"no-unused-expressions": [
  2,
  {
    "allowTaggedTemplates": true
  }
],
"no-param-reassign": [
  2,
  {
    "props": false
  }
],
"no-console": 0,
"import/prefer-default-export": 0,
"import": 0,
"func-names": 0,
"space-before-function-paren": 0,
"comma-dangle": 0,
"max-len": 0,
"import/extensions": 0,
"no-underscore-dangle": 0,
"consistent-return": 0,
"react/display-name": 1,
"react/no-array-index-key": 0,
"react/react-in-jsx-scope": 0,
"react/prefer-stateless-function": 0,
"react/forbid-prop-types": 0,
"react/no-unescaped-entities": 0,
"jsx-a11y/accessible-emoji": 0,
"react/jsx-filename-extension": [
  1,
  {
    "extensions": [
      ".js",
      ".jsx"
    ]
  }
],
"radix": 0,
"no-shadow": [
  2,
  {
    "hoist": "all",
    "allow": [
      "resolve",
      "reject",
      "done",
      "next",
      "err",
      "error"
    ]
  }
],
"quotes": [
  2,
  "single",
  {
    "avoidEscape": true,
    "allowTemplateLiterals": true
  }
],
"prettier/prettier": [
  "error",
  {
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "singleQuote": true,
    "printWidth": 100,
  }
],
"jsx-a11y/href-no-hash": "off",
"jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": [
  "warn",
  {
    "aspects": [
      "invalidHref"
    ]
  }
]
 },

"plugins": [
// "html",
"prettier"
 ]
}
```

Thank Shaun

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple eslinterc file?

Comment: Nope...I only have one eslintrc file.

Comment: Any fix on this? having similar issues.